# C# XAMARIN Bind image (ListView ImageCell)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm really new to Xamarin and Xamarin forms and I need some help.

I have a form of news with text and image. Image transmission is already configured for this form.

I am trying to create a new form with list of news with small image preview near text. I want to use the same image transmission but I can't bind it for XAML `ImageCell`. How I can do it?

XAML selected news form

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Project.Mobile.Client.Portable.Views.News.NewsReadPage"
             xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
             Title="News">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView Padding="10">
            <StackLayout>
                <StackLayout x:Name="ImagesLayout"></StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                       Font="Bold, 20"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Body}"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

XAML.CS

```
namespace Project.Mobile.Client.Portable.Views.News
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class NewsReadPage : ContentPage
    {
        public NewsReadPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var handler = new NativeMessageHandler();
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
            var authData = string.Format("{0}:{1}", Settings.Username, Settings.Password);
            var authHeaderValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authData));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authHeaderValue);

            ImageService.Instance.Initialize(new Configuration
            {
                HttpClient = client
            });
        }
        protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
        {
            base.OnBindingContextChanged();

            if (BindingContext != null)
            {
                this.ImagesLayout.Children.Clear();
                foreach (string path in (BindingContext as Models.News).Pictures.Split(';'))
                    this.ImagesLayout.Children.Insert(0, new CachedImage()
                    {
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        CacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromDays(30),
                        DownsampleToViewSize = true,
                        Source = Settings.ServerUrl + "/api/File/" + path
                    });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How I can use it in `ImageSource="{Binding Pictures}"` for new list of news?

New XAML list

```
<StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="Lst"
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding items}"
                  ItemTapped="OnItemTapped"
                  IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ImageCell Height="100"
                         Text="{Binding Title}" 
                         Detail="{Binding Body}"
                         ImageSource="{Binding Pictures}"
                         TextColor="Red"
                         DetailColor="Gray">
                </ImageCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: where is the items list you are using for your ItemSource?  And I don't know what you're trying to do with OnBindingContextChanged

Comment: @Jason hes using CachedImage, which when bound to a listview's view cells can be buggy sometimes, so its recommended to update the cell when the binding context changes. But he should create a custom view cell, and then listen to when the binding context changes in there, not in the content page.

Comment: @Jason I tried to reformulate this in a new question. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48716966/c-sharp-xamarin-imageurl).  If it is possible, please take a look of it.