# C# Xamarin ImageURL

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have model with 3 fields : TItle, Body, Picture.

```
 public class Names
    {   [PrimaryKey]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public string Picture { get; set; }}
```

Field 'Picture' is a string value which is a part of url of image.
So real URL will looks like:

```
Source = Settings.ServerUrl + "/api/File/" + Picture
```

How I can use such url for imagesource of imagecell in xamarin?

Example of current XAML:
[image]

Example of current XAML.CS

```
namespace Project.Mobile.Client.Portable.Views.Names
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class NamesListPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Models.Names> items { get; set; }

    public NewPage()
    {
        items = new ObservableCollection<Models.Names>();
        this.BindingContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();

        // Disabling selection
        Lst.ItemSelected += (sender, e) => {
            ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
        };

        Lst.Refreshing += (sender, e) => {
            LoadUsersData();
        };
        LoadUsersData();
    }

    public async void LoadUsersData()
    {
        Lst.IsRefreshing = true;

        var names = await App.Database.Names.GetItemsAsync();
        items.Clear();


        foreach (var item in names)
            items.Add(item);

        Lst.IsRefreshing = false;
    }

    public async void OnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        NamesReadPage readPage = new NamesReadPage();
        readPage.BindingContext = e.Item as Models.Names;

        await Navigation.PushAsync(readPage);
    }
}
```

I added xaml code as image because of code limit. Sorry for that.

Comment: either use a ViewModel with a Property that expands the full URL, or use a ValueConverter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Via an `IValueConverter`

```
public class PictureURLConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Settings.ServerUrl + "/api/File/" + (string)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

#### Add the namespace of your IValueConverter

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SameNameSpace;assembly=SomeAssemblyName"
```

#### Add the IValueConverter to your ContentPage.Resources

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:PictureURLConverter x:Key="pictureURL"></local:PictureURLConverter>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

#### Consume the converter in your binding

```
<Image Source="{Binding Picture, Converter={StaticResource pictureURL}}" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.
If it is possible may I ask you to add simple authorization `admin/admin` in your example?

Answer (score 1):

Create a viewModel and change your property to return your desired url and bind this property to your `Image` `Source`.

```
public string PictureUrl
{
    get
    {
        return Settings.ServerUrl + "/api/File/" + this.PictureUrl;
    }
    set
    {
        this.PictureUrl = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("PictureUrl");
    }
}
```